# Save replace value in vim

Tags: vim

How I can save a replace value to register or somewhere? For example

```
:s/foo/new/g
```

So then I can use `new` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have something in a register that you want to use as the replacement in a regular expression, just read it in to the :-command line at the point where you need the data by typing <kbd>control-r</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> where `x` is the name of the register you used.

Or you could use the special `\=` string in the replacement.  When the replacement string starts with `\=` everything after is evaluated as an expression, so you can do something like:

```
:s/foo/\=@x/g
```

Again, where `x` is the name of the register you used.  This lets you use variables names as well:

```
:let new="new string"
:s/foo/\=new/g
```

See:

```
:help c_ctrl-r
:help sub-replace-special
```

Comment: No, I want to save value that was used for replacement.

Comment: You'd basically have to do that manually, either by putting it into a register or a variable.  Vim saves the last search pattern, but not the last replace pattern.